# Does emacs ido support flex matching in buffers?

Tags: emacs

I found ido to be very helpful in finding files (C-x C-f) and buffers (C-x b) especially with flex matching enabled. I also installed smex (built on top of ido) in order to do the same thing with commands. Is it possible to use ido to complete words in the open buffer?

For example, in a buffer which contains these words `stackoverflow-questions` `stackoverflow-tags` `stackoverflow-users`, `sofq` should complete to `stackoverflow-questions`.

Answer (score 2):

IDO's got a great bunch of various helper functions that are easy enough for one to refine into usable components. The following snippet of a function is surprisingly quick but doesn't integrate perfectly with the existing ways of completion:

```
(defun buffer-completion ()
  "Use IDO to pick completion matches from current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((words (split-string (buffer-string))))
    (insert (ido-completing-read "Word completion:" words)))
```

To further smoothen the usage of our completion we could use `thing-at-point` or equivalent function to skip distracting minibuffer prompts.